# How to change Azure VM Spot Priority

Tags: azure

I recently deployed Azure VMs using spot instances (capacity and I would like to change it to regular VMs.   I tried running the following command under azure cli:

> az vm update -n TESTVM -g TEST --priority Regular

I encountered the following error under azure cli:

> Changing property 'priority' is not allowed.

How do I change my spot VMs to regular VMs?

Thanks

Comment: Is your VM running when you try this? If so try de-allocating it then running again

Comment: The VM is deallocated when I run the commands